# Write TFS version/build into placeholder/variable in checked-in text file

Tags: version-control, tfs, build, placeholder

Is there a way to write the build or label into some kind of variable or placeholder in a textfile as sson as it is labeled or checked in ?

We are versioning our database packages in TFS and would like to auto-fill 2 variables during the check-in and labeling processes.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you cannot do it.

The solution is to move your packaging logic to the build/CI phase. Standard Builds automatically place a label on sources so you can use the same data for you purposes.

If you search for "tfs build versioning" to get lot of ideas, in 2013 the easiest way is adding a Powershell script as described by Alkampfer in [Versioning assembly during TFS 2013 build with Powershell Scripts](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/01/11/customize-tfs-2013-build-with-powershell-scripts/).